# Windows Cmd : Delete files from a folder

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a text file that contains files names (pictures) in each line:

```
Pic1.png
Pic2.jpg
Pic3.png
Pic4.gif
```

Is there a batch command to fetch all those file names from the .txt file and delete them?

I tried this : `for /f "delims=" %%f in (files.txt) do del "%%f"`
but i have error : %%f was unexpected

Thanks

Comment: You need `%%f` in a batch file, but `%f` on the command line. If you use `%%f` on the command line, you get the error you are getting.

Comment: You tagged your question [tag:batch-file], so you'll receive answers for that; if you want an answer relating to `cmd` (command prompt) also, tag it [tag:cmd] additionally...

Comment: you are right, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this with a batch file :

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type files.txt') Do (Del /F /Q "%%a")
pause
```

On command line you should do like this :

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('Type files.txt') Do (Del /F /Q "%a")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `/F` option of `for` means that it will read the `file.txt` argument and affect the a variable to each token of the file. No need to specify delimiter when there's one item per line or separated by blanks.

in a .bat file you have to double the '%' chars

```
for /F %%a in (file.txt) do del /f /q %%a
```

From command line (as stated in the above answer), just remove the extra '%' or you'll have `%%a was unexpected` error that you reported.

```
for /F %a in (file.txt) do del /f /q %a
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

**while read -r file; do rm -- "$file"; done < a.txt**

where a.txt is file name where all the file to be deleted is listed

suppose a.txt contains is

A.java

B.java

C.java

then if you execute below command then all the files listed in a.txt file will be deleted

**while read -r file; do rm -- "$file"; done < a.txt**

Comment: Windows batch, not bash. This will give `'while' is not recognized as an internal or external command`